# Downloading CRU TS 3.0 data with custom temporal range

Tags: r, data, download, climate

I want to download CRU TS 3.0 data from year 1960-1990. However in the website https://catalogue.ceda.ac.uk/uuid/c9dd2107e0b7e8c7b6aca7c34980f679 the data is downloaded from 1901-2006.

Is there anyway that I can make the years customized according to my own preference?

I am user of program R, so perhaps there is a package that can download CRU TS 3.0 through custom range of years.

Comment: Have you tried downloading the full 1901-2006 data and then subsetting it in R?

Comment: If this is open data then I think the place to ask about obtaining that is the [opendata.se]. Using data in R is valid to ask about here but try to always include a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The data is split into 10-year groups. You can download them individually, eg at https://data.ceda.ac.uk/badc/cru/data/cru_ts/cru_ts_4.04/data/pet